# Upload apk to FTP with Jenkins

Tags: android, ftp, jenkins-plugins

I am unable to get an apk to go to  FTP server wiht "Publish Over FTP" plugin.

I have verified I connect to the server during configuring the plugin for connection.

I don't know what path to use as my source file.  Any ideas?

Here is screen shot:
[image]

Here is what my finished apks path in Jenkins appears as:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over#PublishOver-transfer):

> **Remove prefix**
>   If this option is specified then all of the files that are selected in *Source files* **must** start with this path prefix, the publish will fail if a file is selected for transfer and is not below *Remove prefix*.

The "Source files" value looks correct, but you have entered `bin` as "Remove prefix", even although none of your artifacts appear to have `bin` as the top-level directory.

Comment: It's working now, but I only want a file (apk), not the entire file structure.  I am getting the entire path as shown above.  Any way to get just the apk? And any idea if I want to keep the "aligned" or the one with no  suffix?

Comment: You can check the documentation, either on the wiki or by clicking the `(?)` icons next to each field. To only add files and not directories, choose "Flatten files". To exclude the unaligned APK, you can use the "Exclude files" pattern.